# How to cat all files with filename with certain words in unix

Tags: unix, command-line, command, cat

I have a bunch of file in one directory, what I wanted to do is:

```
cat a-12-08.json b-12-08_others.json b-12-08-mian.json >> new.json
```

But there are too many files, is there any command I can use to cat all files with "12-08" in their filename?

I found the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
cat *12-08* >> new.json
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find` to do what you want to archive:

```
find . -type f -name '*12-08*' -exec sh -c 'grep "one" {} && cat {} >> /tmp/output.txt' \;
```

In this way you can `cat` the files with contain the word that you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use a wildcard name:

```
cat *12-08* >>new.json
```

This will work as long as there aren't so many files that you exceed the maximum length of a command line, [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) (2MB on the Linux systems I checked).